# Could not load module 'highlightjs'

Tags: phoenix-framework, brunch

I installed a module using npm:

```
npm install highlightjs --save
```

Then I imported it inside my app.js:

```
import "highlightjs"
```

When I run `mix phoenix.server`, I get this error in the console:

> error: Resolving deps of web/static/js/app.js failed. Could not load module 'highlightjs' from '/Users/[path]/web/static/js'. Possible solution: run `npm install`.

Obviously, running `npm install` doesn't fix it, since it's already installed.

Versions:

```
Brunch: 2.7.4
Phoenix: 1.2.1
```